# How to access .NET Core webapi service launched from VSCode debugger within remote devcontainer from host machine

Tags: docker, .net-core, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I can't access containerised .NET services from host when dll started from remote VSCode's debugger.

I can access the services

- from host machine when the dll is run manually with the dotnet command
- from container (using curl) when dll is run manually or with VSCode debugger

Sample repository: https://github.com/matrumz/stackoverflow-devcontainers-ports-debug

Can access from host when manually run

[image: can access from host when manually run]

Results when launched with VSCode debugger

[image: listening on 5000]
[image: curl works in container]
[image: access fails from host]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the program is launched with the `dotnet` command, the app listens on `http://[::]:80`, but the debugger listens on `http://localhost:5000`.

Lord knows what I'm breaking by doing this, but changing

```
    "stackoverflow_devcontainers_ports_debug": {
...   
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
...
    }
```

to

```
    "stackoverflow_devcontainers_ports_debug": {
...   
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://0.0.0.0:5000",
...
    }
```

solved the issue (just working on HTTP for now).

If someone wants to educate me WHY this works, I'm all ears. Until then: I'll continue to solve problems by copying things that already work!